# AES encryption for repetitive small data packets

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm trying to implement simple AES encryption for small data packets (8bytes, fixed length) being sent from nodes with very little computational resources. Ideally the encrypted data would be a single 16byte packet. The data being sent is very repetitive (for an example, wind velocity packet "S011D023", where S and D would always be in the same place, length would always be 8) The nodes may not have the ability to hold runtime variables (e.g. a frame counter, nonce etc.) but could be implemented if essential. How do I make the solution "reasonably" secure against replay, brute force, any other well known attack? Does adding new random padding bytes to each new packet help in anyway? Thanks.

PS: I posted this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186886/aes-encryption-for-repetitive-small-data-packets) where someone suggested this would be a better place for it.

Comment: Could you delete the copy, then?

Comment: @kelalaka I plan to do that soon.

Comment: What is the maximum size of a packet that you allow? Also, your packet can be compressed like there is no need S and D if you know the structure and the numbers can be codded better than ASCII. In ASCII each needs 8 bit, you may encode a number with a 4 bit, which means you can compress 2 times.

Comment: @kelalaka The maximum size of our data packet would be 8 bytes. I understand that we can reduce the size using various techniques like the ones you've mentioned. We have implemented some of these in our design. I used the above packet example for a simpler explanation.

Comment: Once you write than the exact reduced size, we can talk about rest of it. One more question: can you send two or more packages one is data and time etc. and the other is a small HMAC etc?

Comment: As I mentioned above, the exact / reduced size would be 8 bytes. Sending two or more packets should not be an issue while keeping the overall / total data transmission as small as possible.

Comment: You can use AES in CTR mode so that you may encrypt in bits from 1 to 128 for an AES encryption. The problem is the IV that CTR requires. The insecure ECB mode that doesn't require IV will need to encrypt 16 bytes. There is an FFX mode of encryption that preserves the format, though might be slow, that can be helpful. You may go to DES or lightweight cipher with 64-bit block size.

Comment: Once you chose the encryption method, let the next block be frame counter information and the next one is the truncated HMAC. 3 blocks.

Comment: Are you really just sending data like wind direction and speed?  If so, why does it need to be encrypted?  Couldn't you just send the data in plain text and digitally sign it to ensure that it's authentic?

Comment: @Swashbuckler Some 3rd part can steal this information and publish a paper faster than you? [b-degnan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/216359/b-degnan) told this before.

Comment: @kelakaka it all depends on what the data is being used for.  That's unclear, which is why I asked the question.  An issue I have some times with teams is they have a solution in mind and I answer the question they ask instead of asking them what they're trying to do because sometimes they've honed in on the wrong solution.  That may be the case here, it may not.

Comment: @kelakaka Thanks. I'll read about all your suggestions and get back.

Comment: @Swashbuckler I agree with you for the most part, probably don't need encryption. However, we also need to send back replies where we also have addressing / re-addressing commands. In future we may have other nodes where the data could be more confidential, we are trying to plan for such contingencies in advance.

Comment: @kelakaka stealing & publishing... I never thought about that one!